# Modifying a simple function to be self contained

Tags: javascript

I know this question has a quick one line answer, but I can't wrap my head around how to make this arrow function self contained, using properties properly. It is just a function that counts how many times it has been called. Some help would be appreciated.

```
const countTimes = () => {
    countTimes.count = countTimes.count + 1;
    return countTimes.count;
};
countTimes.count = 0;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "self contained"?

Comment: by self contained, I mean that the function shouldn't rely on anything outside of its body

Comment: Does it need to be an arrow function? Because those inherit the surrounding context rather than creating their own.

Comment: @HereticMonkey — If it had a different context and stored the data on that, then it would still be storing data outside the function body, so that wouldn't help.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah I just noticed hence why I removed my comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out how many times a function is called with javascript/jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517562/how-do-i-find-out-how-many-times-a-function-is-called-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @Quentin Depends on the OP's definition of "function body", as your comment on Andy's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 3):

The function body exists only during execution and starts from fresh each time the function is called. If you want to persist data between invocations of the function then you **must** store that data outside the function body (be it as a property on an object, a closed-over variable, a global or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure):

```js
function countTimes() {
  let count = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++count;
  }
};

const count = countTimes();

console.log(count());
console.log(count());
console.log(count());
```

Comment: The `count` variable is still stored outside the body of the function (well, the function that actually gets called when you call `count`).

Comment: I suppose it depends which function shouldn't violate the "function shouldn't rely on anything outside of its body" rule.